# Flatpickr stop text input and remove Iphone default calender

Tags: css, iphone, flatpickr

Using flatpickr for our calendars, are we running into issue with the Iphone/Ipad. On calender open, the curser is 'in' the text box, which triggers the default Iphone calender as shown beneath.
This works 100% on android and chrome mobile simulation.

does any know how to disable

```js
let config = {
            ...this.minDate ? { minDate: this.minDate.toDate() } : {},
            ...this.maxDate ? { maxDate: this.maxDate.toDate() } : {},
            locale,
            defaultDate: this.date.toDate(),
            dateFormat: DATE_FORMAT,
            disableMobile: true
            }
```

```html
<input type="text" data-input="" class="form-control wdio-arrival qa-arrival-date-input book-box-datepicker flatpickr-input active" aria-label="Arrival date" readonly="readonly">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put onfocus=this.blue() and readonly in the html

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" class="form-control" @input="onInput" v-on:click="manualClose" readonly/>
```